# Are there use cases in which it dangerous to use semaphores without extending lifetime through shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore, c++20

I am currently using void futures for thread synchronization in the following setting: thread A submits thread B to the message thread queue to produce a resource needed for thread A. Thread A waits on the resource, but will give up if it takes too long and will then proceed without the functionality that the resource would provide.

With futures, the call to Thread B looks like the following (in pseudocode):

```cpp
/* Thread B function signature: void ThreadB(std::promise<void> p); */

std::promise<void> promised_resource;
std::future<void> future_resource {promised_resource.get_future()};
SubmitToMessageThread([p = std::move(promised_resource)]() mutable { ThreadB(std::move(p)); }));
if (future_resource.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::future_status_ready)
   /* work with resource if thread B has called p.set_value() to indicate the resource is ready */;
else
  /* make do without the resource */
```

The message thread lasts longer than thread A, but thread B is *moved* the `promise`, so thread B has full control over the promise's lifetime, and shouldn't be at risk of accessing the `promise` after its destruction even if thread B is running after thread A finishes. The split between a `promise` and a `future` allows each thread to be in control of the lifetime of the object it is responsible for.

The situation is different with semaphores, as there is just one object (the `semaphore`) shared between two threads. Initially, I was going to provide thread B a reference to the `semaphore`. That would work when there is a guarantee that thread B will not outlive thread A. But in my setting, that is not the case. Does this mean I have to use a `shared_ptr` (or other similar mechanism) in addition to the `semaphore`?

Comment: Why would you pass a shared pointer by reference to another thread?

Comment: I wouldn't. The alternative would be to not instantiate a shared pointer and just pass the semaphore by reference.

Comment: No, the alternative would be to pass the shared_ptr *by value*, so that both threads control its lifetime. `promise/future` simply hide the shared pointer for you.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question to show what the alternative would be--it doesn't involve shared pointers at all, and it looks like the alternative is a bad idea (passing the semaphore by reference).

Comment: I fully understood what you said. I don't understand why you think passing things to a thread by reference is a good idea, whether it's a semaphore or some other shared object. I mean, you understand that passing the `promise` by reference is bad and you therefore passed it properly by value (move).

Comment: Passing by reference is potentially dangerous but would work in the situation where you could guarantee that Thread A outlives Thread B. And this would be the case in many settings where you are using a semaphore with `wait` instead of `wait_for`. So some people may never see this issue. That's why I'm bringing it up.

Comment: "*Passing by reference is potentially dangerous but would work in the situation where you could guarantee that Thread A outlives Thread B.*" But you seem aware that this is not your situation, because you pass the `promise` by value. If your code wouldn't work if you passed the `promise` by reference, why do you think passing a semaphore by reference would work?

Comment: I'm not. What I'm getting at is that the usage pattern for promise/future is well-established. For semaphores it is not. And I haven't seen a good discussion of lifetime considerations for semaphores. Maybe it's just me, but I almost did this incorrectly as my first impression was that the STL provided an intrinsically "safe" semaphore, until I sat down and carefully thought about what I was doing. This is a question I know the answer to, but thought was worth posing on SO to help others who might go down the wrong path.

Comment: "*This is a question I know the answer to, but thought was worth posing on SO to help others who might go down the wrong path.*" If you have the answer... why didn't you provide it? It's OK to ask and answer a question at the same time. Also, the "lifetime considerations" for semaphores aren't discussed because they aren't *special*; they're the same lifetime considerations you'd have for any object that gets shared among multiple threads.

Comment: You're right. I should have provided this as a question and answer. Yes, I know the lifetime considerations are the same, but this may represent a novel situation in some settings. For example, a program may have been mainly passing items by value to handle lifetimes and had been avoiding shared objects. With semaphores, you are forced to have a shared item. I'll work on adding an answer and revising the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are responsible for managing the lifetime of the `semaphore` and must take special care when the thread creating the `semaphore` may be outlived by another thread using the `semaphore`.

The naive approach would be to pass the `semaphore` by reference. While that would work if you could guarantee that the reference remains valid for the lifetime of Thread B, that would not be the case in the situation described.

```
/* Thread B function signature: void ThreadB(std::shared_ptr<std::binary_semaphore>& done); */

auto done {std::make_shared<std::binary_semphore>(0)};
SubmitToMessageThread([&done]() { ThreadB(done); }));
if (done.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)))
    /* work with resource if thread B has called done->release() to indicate the resource is ready*/
else
   /* make do without the resource */
```

But Thread B has no such lifetime guarantee. Thread A's `wait_for` could expire before Thread B is finished, and Thread A could go on to completion, causing destruction of the `semaphore` prior to use by Thread B. We have to manage the lifetime, typically with a `shared_ptr`. Such as the following:

```
/* Thread B function signature: void ThreadB(std::shared_ptr<std::binary_semaphore> done); */

auto done {std::make_shared<std::binary_semphore>(0)};
SubmitToMessageThread([done]() { ThreadB(done); }));
if (done.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)))
    /* work with resource if thread B has called done->release() to indicate the resource is ready*/
else
   /* make do without the resource */
```

In summary, semaphores present another foot-gun opportunity unless lifetime is managed carefully.